# Firebase undefined error when array is empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi so I have this function that counts how many time a name appears in a list:

```
fire.firestore()
.collection("eventLikes")
.doc(eventID)
.onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
      
      //}
    // if(docSnapshot.data().ActivityLikes.length === 0) {
        const nameCounts = docSnapshot.data().ActivityLikes.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            acc[cur.name] = (acc[cur.name] || 0) + 1;
        return acc;
}, {});
```

`docSnapshot.data()` is empty at the start and `docSnapshot.data().ActivityLikes.length` is sometimes empty so `[]` in firebase. But in NextJs i keep gettin this error:

[image]

How should i go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 1):

If the document doesn't exist then `.data()` returns `undefined`. You should if that exists first:

```
if (docSnapshot.exists) {
  // process data
} else {
  console.log("Document does not exists")
}
```